# React-Native using vector-icons in action-bar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Am kinda new to React-Native and mobile development in general

I have two libraries:

```
1. react-native-action-bar
2. react-native-vector-icons
```

`react-native-action-bar` helps in creating an action bar component for my mobile app while `react-native-vector-icons` comes with alot of icons that can be easily added to my project.

`react-native-action-bar` comes with it own icons but there are just too few....

I have no idea how I can use icons from the `react-native-vector-icons` on the Action bar.

I will be glad if anyone can be kind enough to put me through.